# Fill an R array by filling lines first

Tags: r, arrays, vector, line, fill

I would like to convert a vector into an array by filling first the lines of the array (instead of filling first the columns), would someone know a trick to do that? Thanks in advance!

I tried with these lines:

```
v=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
M=array(data=v,dim=c(2,3))
```

But I get the following array:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

While I would like to get

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matrix`

```
> matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), byrow = TRUE, nrow=2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

We can use `array` + `aperm` + transposing in `dim=c(3,2)`

```
> aperm(array(data=v,dim=c(3,2)), c(2,1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

Or simply follow @thelatemail's comment

Comment: I think the `t()` method can happen after the `array` if the `dim=` is adjusted too - `t(array(v, dim=c(3,2)))` , but `matrix` is probably still preferable.

Comment: Ok the array+aperm worked thank you!